# Can VirtualBox guest machine use a virtual USB drive?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I successfully created a virtual USB flash drive following the guide https://bardimin.com/en/technology/how-to-create-a-virtual-usb-flash-drive-in-windows-10/

Now, I want to use this virtual USB in a VirtualBox machine. But when I open VirtualBox machine->Setting->USB, I cannot see my virtual USB. So I'd like to ask if there is any way to create and use a virtual USB with a Virtualbox guest machine?

Thanks so much.

Comment: You created a virtual disk, but it has nothing to do with USB. Its more like a disk you create with Virtualbox - so it should be possible to import it in Virtualbox and attach it to the VM as another disk...

Comment: Or you can mount it on the host and set up "Shared Folder" in the VM.

Comment: thank @Virsacer, what I need is to create a fake (virtual) USB that works as a physical USB stick, and use it as a normal USB in VirtualBox guest, but VirtualBox seems not to support this.

Comment: Virtualbox supports it, but you would need a virtual USB device on your host first - I dont know if a software for that exists...
But why has it to be USB in the VM without beeing physical on the Host? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: "virtual USB device on host" you mean this https://bardimin.com/en/technology/how-to-create-a-virtual-usb-flash-drive-in-windows-10/  . If that, I created one, now what I want is to use it as a normal USB stick. The reason is that we have some members in team, and we need to test something, but don't want all of them have to plug a real USB to their PC. Beside that, we also need to request CI to allow us to use USB, it is so complicated, and we don't want to request for permission.

Comment: As stated before this guide is for creating a virtual disk, but it is definitely NOT a USB device. When you have a disk listed in Device-Manager under USB then you can map it to a VM.

Comment: VirtualBox supports adding a virtual USB controller since version 6.1.x (it is in the same config page for adding SATA and SCSI controllers). There you can attach virtual (disk images) USB disks. Not sure about hot adding, I would guess hot adding the USB controller is not supported, while hot adding disks is. Also, the disk are not marked as type "Removable" but "Fixed". This means they can be partitioned in older Windows (Win10 allows partitioning in both cases). It also means some software will not recognize them as "USB keys".

Comment: Must the disk be of type USB? You can create a "normal" VDI virtual disk in Virtualbox and then attach it to any virtual machine as a SATA disk. Or, as I mentioned in the previous comment, as a USB disk, although for most use cases it should not make a difference.